# Importrange() where the source columns/rows change

Tags: google-sheets, data-import

I have an `importrange("key", "sheet1!D" & targetRow)` formula, but I also need the column of the `importrange()` to be dynamic too in case I add/delete columns in the source data:

E.g. `importrange("key", "sheet1!" &targetColumn &targetRow)`

I researched `query()` language but being forced to use `Col1`, `Col2` etc instead of named column identifiers makes this useless for what I'm trying to achieve.

Can someone help me with this? Easiest way to get column letters without a script? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a somewhat inelegant workaround:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("key", "Sheet!" & IMPORTRANGE("key", "Dept") & targetRow)
```

Where "Dept" is a single-cell named range that contains the column letter of the column I want.

The column letter (e.g. 'K') is the result of the following formula:

```
=substitute(address(row(K6), column(K6),4), row(K6),"")
```

Is there really no easier/more robust way of doing this? This will be used to calculate bonuses so it's actually a very critical spreadsheet.