# IMPORTRANGE () where source columns/rows might change in the original file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the IMPORTRANGE() function to import some columns and rows from another sheet.

I have been trying to find a way where if columns/rows in source sheet change, it wouldn't reflect in the original file. Columns/rows could be deleted or added. Is there a way to do this using IMPORTRANGE() function?

I'm only selecting a number of columns from the original file, so if an extra columns gets added columns will get shifted.

I have looked at `QUERY()` function, but that seems to be static as well, columns are refered to as A,B,C etc too.

The function that I'm currently using is the basic `IMPORTRANGE()` function.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet!range")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importrange() where the source columns/rows change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036381/importrange-where-the-source-columns-rows-change)

Answer (score 1):

try not to use column names just raw rows:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet!1:1000")
```